# Determinant of a matrix where the elements of non-overlapping rows and columns are multiplied by a constant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have a square matrix A and if I take another matrix B such that it contains the same elements as A but has a constant k multiplied to the elements in the non-overlapping rows and columns then what will be the determinant of the B matrix in terms of the determinant of A?

For example :
A is a 3x3 matrix
A = [[ a1, a2, a3],
[a4, a5, a6],
[a7, a8, a9]]

B = [[k*a1, a2,  a3],
[a4,  k*a5, a6],
[a7,  a8,  k*a9]]

Then will det(B) = k*det(A)? If so, how?

Comment: Did you try to work on some examples?

Comment: I think there is probably no reasonable formula for this case. Your hypothesis is of course wrong.

Comment: This already fails when it's the identity matrix